# error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. Flutter windows application won't build

Tags: flutter, msbuild

I was running flutter application on windows and during the build process this message keeps coming and the process will be terminated. I have tried the other option like checking for spaces or cleaning the flutter build but the problem persists.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me after I upgraded my android studio. I have no idea what went wrong, but you can ***fix it by deleting the build folder*** [location of the build folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edTFf.png) every time it happens.